# Info window isn't center position Android Google Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I have problem with info window on Google Map v2. Info window is from left on marker. This is problem reproduced only Samsung Galaxy S4. I installed Google Api Demo and it is reproduced.
Is it bug? How can fix it?

[image]

Comment: user1994379 i have not tested on S4 yet..but is it showing for all the markers positions on map?

Comment: Yes. All markers who used default info window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've submitted this issue on maps v2 tracker.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5439

**Edit:**

Now resolved in the GPServices library.

Answer (score -1):

Are you setting the anchor point in your code? The position looks similar to when I do this:

```
marker.setAnchor(0.0F, 0.0F);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and set the anchor to (0.5,0.5), no luck. Looks to me like a bug

Comment: this doesn't help of course this for the marker not the infowindow