# Android<Map v2>Why the InfoWindow position was not equal to Marker position?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I just follow google development guide do make a simple map with marker, but I was find the problem. Tested on LG-G pro and Sony Z. The InfoWindow is not the same place with the marker. Any one can help?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
    Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                              .position(MELBOURNE)
                              .title("Melbourne")
                              .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
}
```

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771662/info-window-isnt-center-position-android-google-map-v2

Comment: Yes. If you follow link in my answer there, you will see it is fixed and already waiting for a release.